# Require an equivalent code in Java from C# for encryption and decryption

Tags: java, c#, tripledes

We have an application running in .NET for several years. It uses the below c# code for encryption and decryption of password. Now we have another application in Java to consume the same DB for authentication.  Tried various ways but could not get an equivalent code in Java for the below encryption and decryption in C#. As there are lot of data encrypted using this logic and stored in DB, will not be able change the C# code. Could someone help with equivalent code in Java? Thanks in Advance.

```
private string passphrase = "XYZ";
public string EncryptData(string Data)
    {
        byte[] Results;
        var UTF8 = new UTF8Encoding();
        var HashProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] TDESKey = HashProvider.ComputeHash(UTF8.GetBytes(passphrase));
        var TDESAlgorithm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        TDESAlgorithm.Key = TDESKey;
        TDESAlgorithm.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        TDESAlgorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        byte[] DataToEncrypt = UTF8.GetBytes(Data);
        try
        {
            ICryptoTransform Encryptor = TDESAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor();
            Results = Encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(DataToEncrypt, 0, DataToEncrypt.Length);
        }
        finally
        {
            TDESAlgorithm.Clear();
            HashProvider.Clear();
        }
        return Convert.ToBase64String(Results);
    }

    public string DecryptString(string Message)
    {
        byte[] Results;
        var UTF8 = new UTF8Encoding();
        var HashProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] TDESKey = HashProvider.ComputeHash(UTF8.GetBytes(passphrase));
        var TDESAlgorithm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        TDESAlgorithm.Key = TDESKey;
        TDESAlgorithm.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        TDESAlgorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        byte[] DataToDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(Message.Replace(" ", "+"));
        try
        {
            ICryptoTransform Decryptor = TDESAlgorithm.CreateDecryptor();
            Results = Decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(DataToDecrypt, 0, DataToDecrypt.Length);
        }
        finally
        {
            TDESAlgorithm.Clear();
            HashProvider.Clear();
        }
        return UTF8.GetString(Results);
    }
```

Tried Java Code

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
```

public class TripleDESTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String text = "test";

    byte[] codedtext = new TripleDESTest().encrypt(text);
    String decodedtext = new TripleDESTest().decrypt(codedtext);

    System.out.println(codedtext); 
    System.out.println(decodedtext); 
}

public byte[] encrypt(String message) throws Exception {
    final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
    final byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest("XYZ"
            .getBytes("utf-8"));
    final byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);
    for (int j = 0, k = 16; j < 8;) {
        keyBytes[k++] = keyBytes[j++];
    }

    final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
    final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

    final byte[] plainTextBytes = message.getBytes("utf-8");
    final byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainTextBytes);
    // final String encodedCipherText = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder()
    // .encode(cipherText);

    return cipherText;
}

public String decrypt(byte[] message) throws Exception {
    final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
    final byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest("XYZ"
            .getBytes("utf-8"));
    final byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);
    for (int j = 0, k = 16; j < 8;) {
        keyBytes[k++] = keyBytes[j++];
    }

    final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
    final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
    final Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

    // final byte[] encData = new
    // sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(message);
    final byte[] plainText = decipher.doFinal(message);

    return new String(plainText, "UTF-8");
}
```

}

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code converter wesbite

Comment: Perhaps post the Java code that isn't working for comparison?

Comment: Apologies for not posting the tried Javacode. Posted the Java code now

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is not finding equivalent code, but to port your C# code to Java, but because of the C# references and .net assemblies used, to use equivalent Java libs that support Triple DES. Have you investigated equivalent Java libs for Triple Des? A quick search found this example:

https://www.example-code.com/java/crypt2_3des.asp